# Json column with array to record

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I need to write SQL code, that INSERT into some table data, that stored in another table as JSON. PostgreSQL 9.5.

I have a table named **comments**. It has a JSON colum **refs** with data like this:

```json
[{"author":"John","tags":["ruby","rails"]}, {"author":"Nick","tags":["sql"]}]
```

As you can see, there maybe more than one item (pair) in the JSON.

I need to write SQL code, that will take all the records from *comments* where *refs* IS NOT NULL and INSERT INTO **comments_refs** (dont ask why am I need it :) ), that looks like:

```
id                | integer                | not null default nextval(...)
comment_id        | integer                | not null
author            | character varying(255) | not null
tags              | text[]                 | not null default '{}'::text[]
```

I try to play with `json_to_recordset`, but it doesn't work with arrays (see http://postgresql.nabble.com/bug-in-json-to-record-with-arrays-td5828415.html ). Next, I try something like:

```sql
SELECT json_array_elements(rec.refs) FROM comments AS rec;
```

but I do not come up with how to do it .. Maybe somebody can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_array_elements()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
select comment_id, author, array_agg(tag) tags
from (
    select comment_id, e->>'author' author, e->'tags' tags
    from comments, json_array_elements(refs) e
    ) s,
    json_array_elements_text(tags) tag
group by 1, 2;

 comment_id | author |     tags     
------------+--------+--------------
          1 | John   | {ruby,rails}
          1 | Nick   | {sql}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: What is `ref` there?

Comment: The json column; should be `refs`.